# SQL query using alias

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried to write below SQL query in MS SQL server, but it is showing syntax error near **WHERE**.

```
Select ECUID,ECUNAME 
FROM 
(SELECT     [ECU-ID] as ECUID, [ECU-NAME]as ECUNAME FROM         TBL_ECU_MAST)
WHERE ECUID = 147;
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: All subqueries require an alias in SQL Server.  I view this as a typographical error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Gordon suggested you have to give an alias name for the SubQuery used within the SQL Statement

> ```
> SELECT ECUID,ECUNAME 
> FROM 
>   (SELECT [ECU-ID] AS ECUID, [ECU-NAME] AS ECUNAME FROM TBL_ECU_MAST) T
> WHERE T.ECUID = 147;
> ```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 3):

Just give your expression an Alias;

```
Select aliasHere.ECUID, aliasHere.ECUNAME 
FROM 
(SELECT     
    [ECU-ID] as ECUID, [ECU-NAME]as ECUNAME 
    FROM         TBL_ECU_MAST) aliasHere
WHERE aliasHere.ECUID = 147;
```

Obviously use a more descriptive alias...

Answer (score 3):

you can use another way.like below code

```
;with t as
(
SELECT [ECU-ID] AS ECUID, [ECU-NAME] AS ECUNAME FROM TBL_ECU_MAST
)
SELECT ECUID,ECUNAME 
FROM t WHERE ECUID = 147
```

Answer (score 0):

Give alias name for all sub queries :

```
SELECT A.ECUID, A.ECUNAME 
FROM 
(
  SELECT [ECU-ID] as ECUID, [ECU-NAME]as ECUNAME 
  FROM TBL_ECU_MAST 
) A
 WHERE A.ECUID = 147;
```